# How to Customize the Email template on chatter posts

Tags: chatter, email-template, customization

I want to customize the email template sent on the chatter post of the record with the @user full name to have some fields from the record.

Is this possible, or how can I achieve this?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sushma

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, though there is a few [ideas](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000I6IE) registered to support adding this feature. You may want to vote on one of them.